# Python-docx - How to change table font size?

Tags: python-2.7, python-docx

```
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=1)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Qty'
```

I have to change font size of text 'Qty' in table with one row and one column, how can I make it?

Comment: You may want to consider https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template if you plan to do a lot of styling.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to get the paragraph in the cell. From the documentation of python-docx:

> 3.5.2 _Cell objects:
>   class docx.table._Cell *(tc, parent)*
>
> paragraphs
>   List of paragraphs in the cell. A table cell is required to
>   contain at least one block-level element and end with a paragraph. By
>   default, a new cell contains a single paragraph. Read-only

Reference: [python-docx Documentation - Read the Docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/python-docx/latest/python-docx.pdf)

**The code:**

To change font size of text 'Qty'

```
paragraph =hdr_cells[0].paragraphs[0]
run = paragraph.runs
font = run[0].font
font.size= Pt(30) # font size = 30
```

To change font size of the whole table:

```
for row in table.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        paragraphs = cell.paragraphs
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                font = run.font
                font.size= Pt(30)
```

Reference of how to access paragraphs in a table: [Extracting data from tables](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/13)

Comment: Thanks for solution!

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: This helped me too, thanks! I would have liked it if it was easier to set the table font size for the whole table, like I can set the font name and the font italic/bold type for the whole table at once. It seems illogical that you can't set the font size in that way. Is this really the only way?

Answer (score 4):

Up there the solution really helped. I use it for a while. But I found a tiny problem:*time*. As your table grows bigger the time you cost to build the table getting longer. So I improve it. Cut two rounds. Here you are:

**The code changes the whole table**

```
for row in table.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        paragraphs = cell.paragraphs
        paragraph = paragraphs[0]
        run_obj = paragraph.runs
        run = run_obj[0]
        font = run.font
        font.size = Pt(30)
```

*When you cut two rounds you save the time*

Answer (score 3):

Building on user7609283 answer, here is a short version to set a cell to bold (the cell must contain text before applying format as it looks for the first paragraph):

```
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = "Customer"
    row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.bold = True
```

Answer (score 1):

This font change applies to all cells of a table and is streamlined.  All cells must contain text before being formatted or an index out of range error is thrown:

```
for row in table.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        cp = cell.paragraphs[0].runs
        cp[0].font.size = Pt(14)
```

This next font change applies to a single cell as wanted, in this case the top left cell:

```
tc = table.cell(0, 0).paragraphs[0].runs
tc[0].font.size = Pt(14)
```