# How do I change the font color in the cell under the table in the Word document?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I tried to use `document.styles['Normal'].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 255)` to change the font color in the table, but it made all of the colors change in the fonts of the table. Am I missing something?

```
import docx
from docx.shared import RGBColor

# Create Table
document = docx.Document()
table = document.add_table(rows=2, cols=2)
table.style = 'Table Grid'

#Change the font Color to Blue
document.styles['Normal'].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(50, 0, 255)  # Blue Color
document.tables[0].rows[0].cells[0].text = "Blue"

#Change the font Color to Red
document.styles['Normal'].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)  # Red Color
document.tables[0].rows[1].cells[1].text = "Red"

document.save('result.docx')
```

After execution, the outcome is below:

[image]

Hope the result of the execution is below:

[image]

Comment: Assuming it matches VBA, have you tried... `document.tables[0].rows[0].cells[0].font.color = RGBColor(0, 0, 255) # Blue`

Comment: @tresf after trying the suggestion, the error message shows up "AttributeError: '_Cell' object has no attribute 'font', It seems not working,

Comment: Ok, according to this article, you will need to get the paragraph first.  Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43012326/3196753

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66358876/3196753), you can set the cell color directly after you get the paragraph object.

```py
# Change the font Color to Blue. 
document.tables[0].rows[0].cells[0].paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(50, 0, 255)  # Blue Color
document.tables[0].rows[0].cells[0].text = "Blue"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply to my message and provide the solution; it Worked!